# show.legend = FALSE not working for two geom_points

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I can't seem to suppress the legend using `show.legend = FALSE` when I combine two `geom_point`s. It seems very strange as individually, they are working fine.

[Plot 1 with 4 unique shapes using interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HQje.png)

[Plot 2 with 2 unique shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Boj.png)

[Plot 3 with both geom_points gives 6 unique shapes when show.legend = FALSE for plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqDCO.png)

Eventually, I only want Plot 1's legend. I've put theme_bw() at the start of it and everything else, but nothing seems to work... help! My code is below,

```
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(data1,
             mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, shape = interaction(a, b)),
             size = 6,
             alpha = 1,
             position = position_nudge(ifelse(data1$b == "b1", -0.3, 0.3)),
             show.legend = TRUE) +
  geom_point(data2,
             mapping = aes(x=x, y=y, shape = a),
             alpha = 0.6,
             size = 2.5,
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.15),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
   labs(x = "x", y = "y") +
   scale_x_discrete(labels = c("cond1","cond2", "cond3"))
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying this, the above doesn't work, but a mate made it work using a hacky way (i.e., filter the data and create another geom_point). Specifically,

```
geom_point(data2 %>% filter(a == "a1"),
             mapping = aes(x=x, y=y),
             shape = "circle",
             alpha = 0.6,
             size = 2.5,
             position = position_nudge(-0.15),
             show.legend = FALSE) +
geom_point(data2 %>% filter(a == "a2"),
             mapping = aes(x=x, y=y),
             shape = "square",
             alpha = 0.6,
             size = 2.5,
             position = position_nudge(0.15),
             show.legend = FALSE)
```